# C++ redirect outgoing connections

Tags: c++, redirect, hook, firewall

Is there any way in C++ on windows to monitor a program and redirect any outgoing requests it makes on a specific port? I have a simple C++ http proxy and want it to be able to automatically redirect all browser requests on port 80 through itself.

Comment: you didn't specify the OS -- its easier on unix variants.

Comment: Oh sorry windows. on linux it's an iptables oneliner lol.

Comment: Normally programs can not interfere with other programs. That would be a security violation. You need to set your browser (or other app) to explicitly use the proxy.

Comment: I know it's possible. Proxifyer does it.

Comment: I believe programs like proxifyer and fiddler, etc. all rely on the windows proxy detection facilities.  This would only work for applications that actually use the windows proxy facilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple way to do it is to create a Windows kernel hook to trap socket requests and reroute them to your proxy.

Some useful documentation on this is:

http://www.internals.com/articles/apispy/apispy.htm

If you're using Windows Vista or better, consider Windows Filtering Platform (WFP):

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/network/wfp.mspx

Also consider looking at [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) (commercial) and [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) (free). They significantly simplify the process of writing hooks and redirecting API calls (both Win32 and Application).

Answer (score 1):

The program would have to be run with administrative privileges in kernel mode of the host OS.

While I don't have extensive experience with windows kernel hooks, in BSD and linux its trivial to install a kernel module that over-writes the system calls for creating sockets and could easily redirect all sockets to a proxy socket of choice.

Comment: If everyone used linux, our jobs would be a lot easier in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [any destination port] to [one port] then you will have to rely on special drivers. The problem with windows is the inability to natively block [drop] packets. For example a common solution is winpcap. However, while you can monitor traffic, you cannot stop the traffic or modify it in a useful way.

On windows the only solution I've seen would be to use some [open TUN/TAP adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP). With that, you would be able to modify every packet that leaves your system.

If you know beforehand the destination port you will be using then it gets rather simple. Simply write a passthrough c++ socket program that will only change the destination port.

If you want to redirect browser requests then you can simply edit the settings in your browser.

Comment: Doesn't WFP (windows filtering platform) allow exactly what you're saying windows cannot do?!